# How to install less-plugin-clean-css in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, less-plugins

I am trying to install Odoo 10 in my Ubuntu 16.04 PC and came across with **sudo npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css** command. When I trying that line it gives me following error. Please help me to solve this

[image]